# Section character (§) overflows char type (C++)

Tags: c++, type-conversion, char, ascii, overflow

When trying to define the char:

```
char q = '§';
```

clion throws an error: "Character too large for enclosing character literal type". This is weird as if I look up the ascii conversion of § it is just 167.

If I use:

```
char c;
std::string q = "§";
for (char el:q) {
    c = el;
    std::cout << c;
}
```

the output reads: ┬º

and:

```
int c;
std::string q = "§";
for (char el:q) {
    c = (int) el;
    std::cout << c;
}
```

outputs: -62-89

So it seems that the character overflows the char type

I am implenting RSA encryption using unsinged long long int instead of int in this case and the overflow still occurs which corrupts the decrypted data. How can I convert this character and potentially others that may overflow the char type into their respective ascii value (for this example (char)'§' should return 167).

conversion with unsigned long long int:

```
#define ull unsigned long long int

int main() {
    ull c;
    std::string q = "§";
    for (char el:q) {
        c = (ull) el;
        std::cout << c;
    }

}
```

output: 1844674407370955155418446744073709551527

using wchar_t also did not fix the issue.

Comment: `'§'` is probably not a character in the default character encoding and probably belongs to some multi-byte encoding.

Comment: 167 > 127, yes?  Probably, you want `unsigned char`

Comment: Ah. I see the problem. You're looking `'§'` up in an [**extended** ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII), not an ASCII table. These extensions are often proprietary and often result in chaos.

Comment: Worse, since you're printing out 2 characters when encoded as a string it looks like you aren't quite getting the extended ascii version either. 62 -89 all nicely converted into Hex with endian taken into account will be C2A7 (and A7 -> 167 decimal), so a few years of hard living has me thinking you got UTF-8.

Comment: @PaulSanders yes, thank you. Using unsigned char in the conversion was the trick that makes it work. I just wonder why it did not work with wchar_t as that should include extended ascii

Comment: _using wchar_t also did not fix the issue_ Well, you didn't show us _how_ you're using it...

Comment: @user4581301 A few years of hard living has me thinking, period

Comment: @PaulSanders in the second code I show if you replace "char el" by "wchar_t el"

Comment: The trouble is that '§' is not a byte its a multiple bytes that represents a unicode codepoint `00A7`. Looking at the UTF-8 representation of this codepoint we get the econding: `C2` `A7` or `194(-62)` `167(-89)`

Comment: @MartinYork Assuming that the file being compiled is encoded as UTF-8, I think.  Which it probably is (and fits the evidence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go around it is to use unicode string:

```
auto q = u"\u00A7";
```

Unicode strings (`u` for 16-bit and `U` for 32-bit) can in general be used similarly to normal `std::string` type but when you iterate over it or index into it, you'll have the corresponding character type: `char16_t` or `char32_t`.

Comment: I think their issue might have been _Unicode strings (u for 16-bit and U for 32-bit) can in general be used as normal std::string_  Needs to be `std::wstring`, surely.

Comment: @PaulSanders I meant, similarly - changing 'as' to 'similarly to'. Surely it's a distinct type.